What does the ACPI docs about NUMA nodes mean by "dynamic migration"?
With reference to the following section of the ACPI docs about NUMA nodes: https://drops.dagstuhl.de/storage/01oasics/oasics-vol116-parma-ditam2024/OASIcs.PARMA-DITAM.2024.3/OASIcs.PARMA-DITAM.2024.3.pdf
what does "dynamic migration of the devices" mean?
Does it refer to physically migrating stuff (e.g. physically moving a DIMM from one slot to another), or is it referring to a logical operation (e.g. nothing changes physically)?
